# how keep same css on other pages after change

Tags: javascript, css

what i am trying to do is: Change the css of a page with javascript (already done) and keep that css when i navigate to a different page.
I'm trying to make my user have his/her desired css while browsing without the need to keep selecting it.
What i have so far is:

**Javascript**

```
var css="mycss.css";

function cssChange(id){
    css="mycss.css";
    document.getElementById(id).href='mycss.css';   
}
function cssChange2(id){
    css="mycss2.css";
    document.getElementById(id).href='mycss2.css';
}
function cssChange3(id){
    css="mycss3.css";
    document.getElementById(id).href='mycss3.css';
}
function loadpage(){
    document.getElementById('css').href=css;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <link id="css" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload="loadpage()">
```

So am i missing something? Or, perhaps it can't be done with javascript?
Also my css works fine in all pages and all css are how i want them in the pages. It just won't stay the same.

Comment: you'll need to store the user's css selection either server-side or using cookies.

Comment: Or using localStorage or sessionStorage.

Comment: i't for a presentation so i don't have a server, all my files are local in a folder. So what should i use?

Comment: localStorage would be a good option, for newer browsers (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox etc). On every page load you could then retreive the localStorage value and set the CSS based on that. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΝικολαρόπουλος [localStorage](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-storage/Storage/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-storage/Storage/sessionStorage). Both is [supported down to IE 8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Comment: So..what kind of changes are you making using javascript? Is it font size, color, background etc. or is it any kind of structural change..

Comment: no structure. i swap the css file. they change only images font and colors

Answer (score 0):

Better try to maintain the unique css file name for all users along with their profile table. Trigger the CSS file names, while the users logged in. [IT IS SERVER SIDE]

OR

If you are not maintaining the separate tables for users, then track the IP of them, store it in table & show them a choosen style. [IT IS SERVER SIDE]

OR

as above commented, use cookies. [IT IS CLIENT SIDE]

I prefer server side scripting than client side for above.

Answer (score 0):

If it's related to only font, color and image change, I would suggest the below tricks:

Create same name CSS class with different "ID" in a single CSS file, like

```
#type1 .fontClass { font-size: 12px;}

#type2 .fontClass {font-size: 16px;}

#type3 .fontClass {font-size: 20px;}
```

Now you need only one COOKIE set code which basically stored the #ID value (type1 or type2 or type3), on the page load set this ID in to your body tag or the parent DIV tag where you are basically applying the classes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

You can leave a style defined according to the user's cookie. And also set the time that the cookie will be enabled in the user's browser.